# help with python ctypes and nvapi

Tags: python, ctypes

My end goal is to query NVAPI for gpu usage and other statistics in python.  See http://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi

```
from ctypes import WinDLL
nvapi = WinDLL("nvapi.dll")
print nvapi# <WinDLL 'nvapi.dll', handle 718a0000 at 27c0050>
print nvapi.nvapi_QueryInterface# <_FuncPtr object at 0x026D8E40>
print nvapi.nvapi_QueryInterface()# returns 0
print nvapi.NvAPI_Initialize# AttributeError: function 'NvAPI_Initialize' not found
print nvapi.NvAPI_SYS_GetChipSetInfo# AttributeError: function 'NvAPI_SYS_GetChipSetInfo' not found
```

Here is a copy of the header file available for download from the link above: http://paste.pound-python.org/show/7337/

At this point, I am just trying to familiarize myself with the api... so what am I doing wrong?  I can't figure out how to call any of the functions listed in the header file.

Comment: I have posted a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165628/use-python-ctypes-to-interface-with-nvapi-follow-up-with-demonstration-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from your comment:

> NvAPI_Initialize call still fails.
>   saying the function is not found.

`NvAPI_Initialize` is not exported from the dynamic library nvapi.dll. It is a symbol contained in nvapi.lib, the static library shipped with the NVIDIA SDK, thus it's no wonder you are unable to call it using Python.

Honestly, the easiest route here is to create a small wrapper DLL in C, statically linking to nvapi.lib and exposing a friendly interface to Python.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's a WinDLL? From the header file, it looks like a standard C calling convention to me. Have you tried `CDLL` instead?

**EDIT**:

I see now. The header you pointed to isn't actually the interface for `nvapi.dll`--it is a wrapper around it that must be statically linked.

From the docs downloaded from [NVIDIA's developer site](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvapi):

> **Use a Static Link with Applications**
>
> NvAPI cannot be dynamically linked to applications. You must create a static link to the library and then call NvAPI_Initialize(), which loads nvapi.dll dynamically.
>
> If the NVIDIA drivers are not installed on the system or nvapi.dll is not present when the application calls NvAPI_Initialize(), the call just returns an error. The application will still load.

I would guess that the actual calls in `nvapi.dll` are completely different than the ones exposed in this wrapper library. I can't seem to find any documentation on those though. Perhaps they are internal and change between systems.

If you want to use this interface, I'm not really sure what the best solution is. It's a static library and not a dynamic one, so ctypes wouldn't handle it unless you wrapped it in another DLL. I'm not an expert at native code with Python, so maybe someone else will have an easy fix. Sorry.

Comment: I tried CDLL as well. It doesn't work either. 
<CDLL 'nvapi.dll', handle 71890000 at 26f8030>
<_FuncPtr object at 0x02608EB8>
0  
but then errors with AttributeError: function 'NvAPI_Initialize' not found

Comment: My formatting got all messed up sorry.  The first three prints work and display similar output, but the NvAPI_Initialize call still fails. saying the function is not found.