# use python ctypes to interface with nvapi (follow up with demonstration code)

Tags: python, ctypes, nvidia

This is a follow up to my previous question: [help with python ctypes and nvapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163770/help-with-python-ctypes-and-nvapi)

I am posting another question because I already selected an answer in my previous question and the question has shifted direction now.

Using python, I am trying to query nvapi.dll to get my gpu usage value.

This is how you would do it in C# (referenced below): http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/source/browse/trunk/Hardware/Nvidia/NVAPI.cs

Because I only need a small subset of the functionality I don't really want to swap into using another language.  I think that ctypes should be able to do this... I just cannot figure out how to do it.  I have never really used Python ctypes before.

In order to query for the gpu usage I first need to call the NvAPI_Initialize function.  One must also use the query interface to reference the function:

```
from ctypes import *
nvapi = WinDLL("nvapi.dll")
nvapi_QueryInterface = nvapi.nvapi_QueryInterface
```

Using the above code, I have access to the nvapi_QueryInterface, but I cannot figure out how to replicate this portion:

```
private static void GetDelegate<T>(uint id, out T newDelegate)
  where T : class
{
    IntPtr ptr = nvapi_QueryInterface(id);
    if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        newDelegate =
          Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(T)) as T;
    }
    else
    {
        newDelegate = null;
    }
}
```

to reference the init and usage functions:

```
GetDelegate(0x0150E828, out NvAPI_Initialize);
GetDelegate(0x189A1FDF, out NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages);
```

My understanding of this may still be wrong, but I've spent a good deal of time trying to figure this out so I hope someone can help push me in the right direction because I am a little lost as to how to proceed.

Can someone help me understand how I can make this small portion of the code work directly in python?  I just need to be able to call the NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages function at the end of the day.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In order to query for the gpu usage I
>   first need to call the
>   NvAPI_Initialize function.

There are actually two initialization functions involved: the one from the static library nvapi.lib, which tries to dynamically load nvapi.dll, locates some functions and calls the second initialization function from the dynamic link library. The steps involved when calling NvApi_Initialize from the *static* library are roughly as follows:

1. Check if nvapi.dll is already
   loaded, if not, load it
2. Use GetProcAddress to get a pointer to
   `nvapi_QueryInterface` from the DLL
   Use the newly obtained function to
   query for the interface with the Id
   **0x150E828**. This   will be the second
   initialization function from the
   dynamic library
3. Call the obtained initialization function. If the
   function was successful (indicated
   by a return value of 0), obtain two
   new function pointers via
   `nvapi_QueryInterface`, using the
   ids **0x33C7358C** (let's call this ENTER) and **0x593E8644** (EXIT).

So, if you want to stay pure Python, you basically have to replicate these steps using ctypes, which would be pretty easy. After you are done, there is a cleanup function in nvapi.dll, which you can query using the id **0xD22BDD7E**. If you are done using the library, remember to call this function.

Now on to the real problem: unfortunately, there is no function `NvAPI_GPU_GetUsages` in the December 2010 NVIDIA SDK. There is, however, `NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx` which will allow you to request an array of structures of type `NV_GPU_DYNAMIC_PSTATES_INFO_EX` to be filled, which in turn will contain the utilization as percentage of time during the last second for a given domain (i.e. GPU, frame buffer and video engine).

Basically, if you want to retrieve GPU usage information, you transfer the `NV_GPU_DYNAMIC_PSTATES_INFO_EX` struct to Python (see [Structures and unions](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) in the ctypes documentation), create an array of at least 3 structures and pass that array to the `NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx` function, which you would have to query from the dynamic link library first, using the id **0x60DED2ED**.

This is, by the way, where the two functions come into play you queries during initialization - it's a sort of locking mechanism. While not strictly necessary (i.e. you can omit this during calling), you are encouraged to call them, i.e.

```
Enter()
NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx(array_of_structs)
Exit()
```

You are supposed to be able to find at at which position in the array GPU usage information is stored by looking at the NVAPI_GPU_UTILIZATION_DOMAIN_GPU macro (or constant), unfortunately, there does not seem to be a declaration included in the header files for the SDK. Still, you could easily verify this by comparing the results of your code with the NVIDIA system tool that displays GPU usage information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was having trouble with this because I assumed I should be using ctypes WinDLL but it turns out that you have to use CDLL.  Once I used CDLL I started getting meaningful results back from the QueryInterface.

Comment: Where do I go to find out the magic numbers that need to be provided to nvapi_QueryInterface?